# Laravel return FALSE if field is NOT NULL (eloquent, whereNotNull)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I try to make the following blade statement work. If a Character is in a Team, display their name:

```
// ranking.blade.php
@if ($character->user->hasTeam()) [{{ $character->user->team->name }}] @endif
```

**Problem**
My solution always returns true, because the query will be executed:

```
// User.php
public function hasTeam()
{
    return ($this->whereNotNull('team_id')->first()) ? true : false ;
}
```

**SQL**

```
// dd($this->whereNotNull('team_id')->toSql());
-> "select * from `users` where `team_id` is not null"
```

### Questions

- Is the whereNotNull method useless in this instance?
- How do I only display a team's name if the User is member of a Team?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check if the `team_id` field of a user is null. This way, no extra queries are required.

```
public function hasTeam()
{
    return isset($this->team_id);
}
```

Comment: Great! That's what I wanted and didn't tought of. Damn :-)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to @Jerodev 's answer, you can also make use of accessors :

```
public function getHasTeamAttribute()
{
    return isset($this->team_id);
}
```

so whenever you need to access the property you can just call

```
$user->has_team
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `$this->whereNotNull('team_id')->first()` return?

Keep in mind that your ternary operator listens to truthy values.

My guess is that you get always true because the query is actuall always getting executed. You would get false only if there was an error connecting to database.